# Merge Sort: exercise

Tags: haskell, recursion, mergesort

I've decided to learn Haskell by following the current Coursera algorithms course using Haskell to implement the algorithms discussed.

First up is merge sort, which I've implemented as shown here. I'm brand new to Haskell so looking for any suggestions for improvements to the code - it seems quite verbose - and pointers on anything I may be doing wrong or in a weird way because I don't know what I'm doing.

```
module Main where

import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  mapM_ putStrLn $ sort args

sort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
sort xs = reduce True $ map (arr) xs

arr :: a -> [a]
arr x = [x]

reduce :: (Ord a) => Bool -> [[a]] -> [a]
reduce _ []            = []
reduce forwards (x:[]) = if forwards then x else reverse x
reduce forwards xs     = reduce (not forwards) (combine forwards [] xs)

combine :: (Ord a)   => Bool -> [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
combine forwards acc []       = acc
combine forwards acc (x:[])   = (reverse x):acc
combine forwards acc (x:y:zs) = let merged = merge forwards x y
                                    acc'   = merged:acc
                                in  combine forwards acc' zs

merge :: (Ord a) => Bool -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge forwards xs ys = mergeIter forwards [] xs ys

mergeIter :: (Ord a) => Bool -> [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mergeIter _        acc [] []     = acc
mergeIter forwards acc (x:xs) [] = mergeIter forwards (x:acc) xs []
mergeIter forwards acc [] (y:ys) = mergeIter forwards (y:acc) [] ys
mergeIter forwards acc (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x <=  y && forwards     = mergeIter forwards (x:acc) xs (y:ys)
    | x > y && not forwards   = mergeIter forwards (x:acc) xs (y:ys)
    | otherwise               = mergeIter forwards (y:acc) (x:xs) ys
```

One specific question I have is around recursive function with accumulator arguments - you'll see in the listing that I've had to create a `mergeIter` function just to allow a default for the initial argument for the accumulator.

As far as I can see Haskell doesn't support default values for arguments - should I be doing something else instead? A fold maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so let's see. `arr x = [x]` is usually called `wrap`, or just the operator section `(:[])` is used. But `map` can also be written with list comprehension, giving us

```
sort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
sort xs = reduce True [[x] | x <- xs]
```

I find it much more visually apparent that way. We usually use short variable names in Haskell, with the same goal. When I see a variable `fw` and then `not fw` I get it that it is a toggle, a flag of some sorts, I don't need to see the long name like `forwardorbackwardsflag` explaining it to me in words while at the same time obscuring this visually. So we get

```
  where
    reduce _ []    = []
    reduce fw [xs] = if fw then xs else reverse xs
    reduce fw s    = reduce (not fw) (combine fw [] s)
```

we make it an internal function to `sort`, because this is what it is. It has no otherwise uses on its own. It's too tailored for the specific use here. -- `(x:[])` is written also `[x]`, which is a lot simpler. -- We don't have to annotate types of everything. Here `reduce` is defined right under its use site, so we see that the initial value of `fw` is `True`. For me, it is self-documenting enough, but YMMV. Next, `combine`. There's no need to name all those interim entities. The name of the function itself isn't right, it's too generic. What it does, specifically, is process the elements of its input list *in pairs*:

```
    rpairs fw acc []       = acc
    rpairs fw acc [x]      = reverse x : acc
    rpairs fw acc (x:y:zs) = rpairs fw (merge fw x y : acc) zs
```

It also builds its result in reversed order. We can make it an internal function to `reduce`, so that *its* argument `fw` could be referred to in `rpairs` body. At the same time there is no need in the separate accumulator really, we can just build the result naturally, in lazy fashion:

```
  where
    reduce _ []    = []
    reduce fw [xs] = if fw then xs else reverse xs
    reduce fw s    = reduce (not fw) (reverse $ pairs s)
      where
        pairs []       = []
        pairs [x]      = [reverse x]
        pairs (x:y:zs) = merge fw x y : pairs zs
```

For `merge` to be able to refer to `fw` it too should be put here as an internal function to `reduce`. It is usual to split such functions into two like you did, the interface function ("the *wrapper*") and the internal *"worker"* function, except that normally the worker is made internal to the wrapper. But here the wrapper itself is too specialized, it reverses its result so is unlikely to be useable in general, so no need for the split. Thus we arrive at:

```
sort    :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
sort xs = reduce True [[x] | x <- xs]
  where
    reduce _  []   = []
    reduce fw [xs] = if fw then xs else reverse xs
    reduce fw s    = reduce (not fw) . reverse . pairs $ s
      where
        pairs (x:y:t)     = rmerge [] x y : pairs t
        pairs [x]         = [reverse x]
        pairs []          = []

        rmerge acc [] []  = acc
        rmerge acc xs []  = reverse xs ++ acc
        rmerge acc [] ys  = reverse ys ++ acc
        rmerge acc (x:xs) (y:ys)
          | fw && x <= y || not fw && x > y
                          = rmerge (x:acc) xs (y:ys)
          | otherwise     = rmerge (y:acc) (x:xs) ys
```

There's no shame in calling `rmerge` with the initial value as we do here, it's just an internal function here, called from another internal function.

---

But actually the reversals that `rmerge` performs are unnecessary, because of Haskell's lazy evaluation. `merge` now becomes a general function, usable in general. `pairs` too. `reduce` performs the same processing step on its input iteratively until a condition is met - there's a higher order function `until` that already captures this pattern. This leads to some more simplification of the code:

```
sort    :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
sort [] = []
sort xs = head $ until (null . tail) (pairwise merge) [[x] | x <- xs]
                                  -- (reverse . pairwise merge) 
pairwise f (x:y:t) = f x y : pairwise f t
pairwise _ t       = t

merge xs []        = xs
merge [] ys        = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
       | x <= y    = x : merge  xs (y:ys)
       | otherwise = y : merge (x:xs) ys
```

I think we would need to toggle between `<=` and `<` in `merge` to ensure the sort's stability, if we were to proceed by `(reverse . pairwise merge)` steps. But, perhaps we can just throw that `reverse` away.

Comment: Heh, looks a lot nicer & shorter... but I don't really understand it. Could you maybe go into how you got from what I'd written to what you've ended up with and why you made the changes you made? I really don't know any Haskell so you might need to explain it in quite basic terms :-)

Comment: I was hoping you'd ask something specific. Start by comparing my 1st code and yours. Convince yourself it does the same thing. If you have questions, ask. :) btw `a . b . c $ x == (a . b . c) x == a $ b $ c $ x = a (b (c x))`.

Comment: @Russell I've added some derivation.

Comment: Phew! That's exactly what I needed, thanks. There was just so much going on I didn't know what to ask. Genuinely amazed by Haskell - it's like learning to program all over again, which is exciting :-).

Comment: Also your version trashes mine in terms of speed - over a randomly chosen 10m numeric strings, mine comes in at 2m23.322s and yours at 1m45.831s. Amazing.

There is one thing I really don't understand though... Presumably your speed increase is down to not needing the `reverse`s, because you've constructed your recursive calls like this: `f x y : pairwise f t` and `x : merge  xs (y:ys)` (which also looks a lot nicer, too) - but doesn't this mean the calls are not tail-recursive? Why don't you get a stack overflow on large input? Is there some magic I don't know about? Thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome. :)  yes, it isn't tail recursion, because of the laziness. In Haskell it's known as "guarded recursion", at times as corecursion. I think it is very close to the [tail recursion modulo cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons). cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057658/lazy-evaluation-and-time-complexity/12057921#12057921 :)

Comment: @Russell As for speed, I'm sure more advanced Haskell using arrays, vectors and such can be faster. But with lists this style usually gives you the best performance.

Comment: @Russell another consideration is "space leaks" - memory retention. If you name something it will want to stay in memory; if you use an expression inline, and there are no back-pointers into it holding on to the long ago seen parts of it, then chances are it will get GC'ed on the fly. For this to happen, you should compile, with -O2 switch, and test the compiled executable at your terminal prompt standalone  (*not* loading compiled file into GHCi, which can leak memory still). Space leaks lead to slowdowns obviously. Run your file as ">name +RTS -s" to see run-time stats on finish.

Comment: !!!!  "tail recursion modulo cons." - now that is very, very cool! Obliterates at a stroke one of the things that makes writing a lot of tail-recursive functions ugly!

Comment: @Russell be sure your language supports it; or implement it on your own (example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13256555/849891)). :)

Comment: Ah, if only Ruby supported tail recursion at all - I'd definitely implement that! I might have a try to see if it's possible to do with `reduce`/`inject`.

Comment: If you happen to be feeling generous... I've just posted a Haskell question on Stackoverflow I get the feeling you'd have no problem answering :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512494/recursive-state-monad-for-accumulating-a-value-while-building-a-list

Comment: btw the standard terminology is "Haskell's guarded recursion". TRMC analogy is something that *I* have been "pushing" but so far none of the bigwigs got on board with that. TRMC is an optimization for strict languages after all. :) For Haskell it is usually called "guarded recursion". Being a big fan of Prolog, I'm a little invested with the TRMC angle. :) -- BTW I once [asked a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9149183/849891). It relates to [this piece of code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers#Direct_calculation_through_triples_enumeration).

Comment: update: the proper term is "guarded corecursion" (as contrasted with "structural recursion"). See the answer by pigworker http://stackoverflow.com/a/3983390/849891. :)

Answer (score 1):

The code looks way to complicated to me, in fact this isn't even the kind of merge sort I'm used to, which is "split the list in two parts, sort the parts, merge them back to one list". Here is a short implementation:

```
sort xs@(_:_:_) =  merge $ map sort $ split xs  
sort xs = xs

split = foldr (\x [l,r]-> [x:r,l]) [[],[]]

merge [x:xs,y:ys]
  | x < y = x : merge [xs, y:ys]
  | otherwise = y : merge [x:xs, ys]
merge xss = concat xss
```

Comment: It was a similar, but much more complicated version of this I did first, but as I was using a linked list I decided that finding the halfway point of the list and splitting it for every recursive call was too inefficient. That's why I decided to try working from the bottom up instead. This is really nice and concise though.

Comment: [1..16] --> [1,3..16] # [2,4..16] --> ([1,5..15]#[3,7..15]) # ([2,6..16]#[4,8..16]) --> ( ([1,9]#[5,13]) # ([3,11]#[7,15]) ) # ( ([2,10]#[6,14]) # ([4,12]#[8,16]) ) ==> access patterns are all over the place, so it seems that this top-down variant will need more space to operate (and so will probably be slower too) than the bottom-up method where the initial access to the input list is one sequential pass. With `split (x:xs) = g (x:) xs xs where g f xs [] = (f [], xs); g f (x:xs) (_:_:ys) = g (f.(x:)) xs ys` top-down is sequential access, but it does repeated traversals of the halves.